# How to get a param from the url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a url like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/#/firstregistration?panel=4?codice=fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262
```

I need to get the param called "codice" from the url of this page and use it in a query. I tried with this code:

```
render() {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
  const codiceHash = params.get('codice');
  console.log(params.get('codice'))
  return (
   <div className={styles}> 
     <div className="notification">
       <h2>Prima Registrazione eseguita con successo</h2>
     </div>
     {this.saveEsegue(email, transactionHash , blockHash, now, "FR", codiceHash)}
   </div>      
  )
}
```

But what I get back from the `console.log` is `null`.
What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you make a console.log of this.props?

Comment: Your URL is very invalid

Comment: @Girgetto in this.props there are a lot of params, but in location i have location:
hash: ""
pathname: "/firstregistration"
search: "?panel=4?codice=b77470a85f42821fd11ec69b53f0edeb3c39392f665a42175f13f7aba90d7671"
state: undefined

Comment: @mplungjan why you say it's invalid?

Comment: ?codice should be &codice

Answer (score 1):

Your URL is invalid. You cannot have # and then later two ? in it.

Your ?codice shoould be &codice

Here is one way to get at codice

```js
const invalidHref = "http://localhost:3000/#/firstregistration?panel=4?codice=fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262&somethingelse"

const codice = invalidHref.split("codice=")[1].split("&")[0];

console.log(codice)
```

Here is how it would have worked on a valid URL

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams("http://localhost:3000/#/firstregistration?panel=4&codice=fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262")

const codice = params.get("codice")

console.log(codice)
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameters string isn't correct in the URL, but to get the string from what you've provided I'd use RegEx.

This way it doesn't matter where the codice parameter is in the URL (ie you can add more parameters without breaking it. RegEx will just pick it out.)

```js
const url = "http://localhost:3000/#/firstregistration?panel=4?codice=fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262"; // window.location.href;
const codice = url.match(/(codice=)([a-zA-Z0-9]*)/)[2];
console.log(codice) // prints fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262
```

Comment: Assuming there are no special chars in the codice field

Comment: yes, that is true I've not included any special chars in the regex; it is not perfect in that sense, but if the URL query was in the correct format there are other tools available to decode URL parameters, such as query-string.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to use the module [querystring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string) to achieve that, this is one of the top used for this purpose.

Example:

```
console.log(this.props.location.search);
//=> '?foo=bar'

const parsed = queryString.parse(location.search);
console.log(parsed);
//=> {foo: 'bar'}
```

Comment: Why, When JS has URL and URLSearchParams that work on valid URLs

Comment: Because your url is not a valid one (2 ?), this is how it works, URLSearchParams might not be supported for the old  browsers https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams

Comment: Yes, what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know. I am not going to load https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string to test your code. You could show us here in a [mcve] to prove it works

Comment: I unfortunately can't use that package on jsfiddle (didn't find a way to load it), but you can see that this example is coming from the doc, this package is downloaded ~7m a week + natively used by angular, react, ...

Answer (score -1):

Since you only want the one parameter and you know which values it can hold I would use regex.

```
var r = /codice=([a-z0-9]+)&/g
var matches = r.exec('http://localhost:3000/#/firstregistration?panel=4?codice=fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262')
console.log(matches[1])
>> fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262
```

Answer (score -1):

The code snippet will return

`codice=fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262`

change `url_string` to `window.location.href` to grab the current URL of the page

```js
var url_string = "http://localhost:3000/#/firstregistration?panel=4?codice=fea023b0cb134b845d49a789a9149ab4321574fe093a5fceac1083959e26d262"; //window.location.href
var b = url_string.substring(url_string.indexOf("?codice=") + 1);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: You can't be certain codice is the last param in the url. This answer is not correct